# How to convert list of key-value tuples into dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list that looks like:

```
[('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)]
```

I want to turn it into a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

What's the best way to go about this?

EDIT: My list of tuples is actually more like:

```
[(A, 12937012397), (BERA, 2034927830), (CE, 2349057340)]
```

I am getting the error `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1916; 2 is required`

Comment: What kind of entities those `A`, `B` (or `BERA`) and `C` (or `CE`) really are? Thanks

Comment: I am willing to bet that the errors produced with the working examples below are related to him not having a list of tuples, but an extremely long list that he wants separated into 2-tuples.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

#### Your error:

Why you are getting the `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1916; 2 is required` error:

The answer is that the elements of your list are not what you think they are. If you type `myList[0]` you will find that the first element of your list is not a two-tuple, e.g. `('A', 1)`, but rather a 1916-length iterable.

Once you **actually** have a list in the form you stated in your original question (`myList = [('A',1),('B',2),...]`), all you need to do is `dict(myList)`.

---

[2021 edit: now also answers the actual question asked, not the intended question about the specific error:]

#### In general:

Either use the usual `dict(iterableOrMapping)` [constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping), or use the [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) `{someExpr(k,v) for k:v in iterable}` syntax:

```
>>> example1 = [('A',1), ('B',2), ('C',3)]
>>> dict(example1)
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

```
>>> {x:x**2 for x in range(3)}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2:4}
```

```
# inline; same as example 1 effectively. may be an iterable, such as
# a sequence, evaluated generator, generator expression

>>> dict( zip(range(2),range(2)) )
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2:2}
```

A [Python dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is an O(1)-searchable unordered collection of pairs {(`k`ey→`v`alue), ...} where keys are any immutable objects and values are any object.

Keys MUST implement the [`.__eq__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)
and [`.__hash__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) methods to be usable in the dictionary. If you are thinking of implementing this, you are likely doing something wrong and should maybe consider a different mapping data structure! (Though sometimes you can get away with wrapping the keys in a different wrapper structure and using a regular dict, this may not be ideal.)

Intermediate or advanced programmers who wish to implement a 'frozen' or 'immutable' type, or one which masquerades as one, must be very careful of implications or else your program will be wrong with **extremely subtle and near-impossible-to-find bugs**:

You can't use a dict if you allow yourself to mutate the object later such that its notion of equality might change. Objects considered equal must always have `__eq__` return True and have `__hash__` return identical values.

The methods must exactly obey the spec. This means that:

- For novices: Hash functions([wikip.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)) let you get a false-positive or true-positive result; `hash(x)==hash(y)` means `x` MIGHT equal `y` and the internal python code must then check `x==y` (`.__eq__`) to confirm it's a true-positive and not a false-positive. This allows O(1) lookup.
- For novices: It is critically important that the `__hash__` value not change for any reason once the object is in its final state. **If you cannot guarantee both this and `hash(x)!=hash(y) implies x!=y`, you should not be using a dict.**
- One might consider a [different type of mapping rather than modifying the data itself](https://eng.lyft.com/hashing-and-equality-in-python-2ea8c738fb9d). This can be equivalent to writing a wrapper object, at the cost of using a library. This is usually not necessary.
- For experts: It should also be noted that the hashes of some default objects are salted and may change between python invocations and versions (this may be a gotcha if you store or network-communicate data in any way that contains python hashes; they are an internal detail that should be regenerated on each process startup).

Python has a bunch of built-in frozen datastructures such as `namedtuple`, `frozenset`, etc., but they are sometimes harder to work with. `tuple` is the basic frozen variant of the basic `list` structure (which would let you store a `{(1, 2): 3, (4, 5): 6}`). It also has some variants of the `dict` structure. If you want to get a map from "frozen dicts" to values, frozendict doesn't exist except as a third-party library, but you can extract the dict's `.items()` as a an unordered `frozenset` of `tuple`s.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how the list got that way but after reworking it from scratch, I was able to fix it.

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K: (assuming context is unrelated to this question) In general, unless it's superfluous or slows your program down, it's perfectly fine to create dicts as helpful indexes into whatever abstract data structure you're implicitly building. The notion of "good practice" is entirely context-dependent; do you need O(1) lookup time for keys? Also you cannot "convert lists to dictionaries" arbitrarily; it entirely depends on the semantics. e.g. `[(1,2), (1,3)]` -> `{1:3}` would clobber your keys and lose info! A dict is a one-to-* relation with O(1) insert/delete time. List is a list.

Answer (score 179):

```
>>> dict([('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)])
{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 2}
```

Comment: Also commented on another answer that suggests the same: This doesn't cover having duplicate tuple 'keys' eg: `l=[('A',1), ('B',2), ('C',3), ('A', 2)]` will result in having `'A': 1` which may not be the desired result.

Answer (score 34):

Have you tried this?

```
>>> l=[('A',1), ('B',2), ('C',3)]
>>> d=dict(l)
>>> d
{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 2}
```

Comment: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1916; 2 is required

Comment: That was a straight cut'n'paste from my terminal, so it should work. Can you show exactly what you did to get that error?

Comment: @Fred, you must have mistyped something, this answer is fine.

Comment: @FredWilson that is the error you usually get when you try something like `dict([string1, string2, string3, string4])`

Comment: @chacham15 `, ..., string1916])` !

Comment: This doesn't cover having duplicate tuple 'keys' eg: `l=[('A',1), ('B',2), ('C',3), ('A', 2)]` will result in having `'A': 1` which may not be the desired result.

Comment: Are you speculating about what requirements could have been added to a year-old question? The OP accepted an answer, and presumably knew what the desired result was better than you.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a way to handle duplicate tuple "keys":

```
# An example
l = [('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('A', 5), ('D', 0), ('D', 9)]

# A solution
d = dict()
[d [t [0]].append(t [1]) if t [0] in list(d.keys()) 
 else d.update({t [0]: [t [1]]}) for t in l]
d

OUTPUT: {'A': [1, 5], 'B': [2], 'C': [3], 'D': [0, 9]}
```

Comment: Awesome! Helped me out.

Comment: great!, helped alot

Answer (score 11):

**If Tuple has no key repetitions, it's Simple.**

```
tup = [("A",0),("B",3),("C",5)]
dic = dict(tup)
```

**If tuple has key repetitions.**

```
tup = [("A",0),("B",3),("C",5),("A",9),("B",4)]
dic = {}
for i, j in tup:
    dic.setdefault(i,[]).append(j)
```

Or:

```
from collections import defaultdict
tup = [("A",0),("B",3),("C",5),("A",9),("B",4)]
dic = defaultdict(list)
for i, j in tup:
    dic[i].append(j)
```

Comment: I still don't understand what setdefault does, can you help me?

Comment: @ArielMarceloPardo `setdefault` (unintelligible name), returns a given element of the dictionary, but if it doesn't exist it creates it using the default value parameter (`[]`, aka empty list, in this case) and returns it.

So if the `i` key in the dictionary doesn't exist yet, it creates it and puts as value an empty list, then `append`s the value `j` to that list. If the key already exists, it appends `j` to the list at that index.

Said this, `defaultdict` is a much better option in this case, but just because it was not possible to come up with a better name than criptic `setdefault`.

Answer (score 4):

Another way using dictionary comprehensions,

```
>>> t = [('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)]
>>> d = { i:j for i,j in t }
>>> d
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l=[['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3]]
d={}
for i,j in l:
d.setdefault(i,j)
print(d)
```