# Python convert pairs list to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of about 50 strings with an integer representing how frequently they occur in a text document. I have already formatted it like shown below, and am trying to create a dictionary of this information, with the first word being the value and the key is the number beside it.

```
string = [('limited', 1), ('all', 16), ('concept', 1), ('secondly', 1)]
```

The code I have so far:

```
my_dict = {}
for pairs in string:
    for int in pairs:
       my_dict[pairs] = int
```

Comment: "string" is perhaps not a good choice for the name of that object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Convert list of key-value tuples into dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586310/python-convert-list-of-key-value-tuples-into-dictionary)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Like this, Python's [`dict()`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-dict) function is perfectly designed for converting a `list` of `tuple`s, which is what you have:

```
>>> string = [('limited', 1), ('all', 16), ('concept', 1), ('secondly', 1)]
>>> my_dict = dict(string)
>>> my_dict
{'all': 16, 'secondly': 1, 'concept': 1, 'limited': 1}
```

Comment: For me it puts the value in a list.
Could you please tell me how to solve it?
{'all': ['16'], 'secondly': ['1'], 'concept': ['1'], 'limited': ['1']}

Answer (score 18):

Just call [`dict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

```
>>> string = [('limited', 1), ('all', 16), ('concept', 1), ('secondly', 1)]
>>> dict(string)
{'limited': 1, 'all': 16, 'concept': 1, 'secondly': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `string` variable is a list of pairs. It means you can do something somilar to this:

```
string = [...]
my_dict = {}
for k, v in string:
  my_dict[k] = v
```

Comment: This can be done in just one line with a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: @AlexThornton I know. But since it seems the OP is just starting with Python I think is a good idea to develop his solution gradually. The dict ctor might seem like magic to someone who starts programming in Python...

Answer (score 1):

Make a pair of 2 lists and convert them to [dict()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
your_dict = dict(zip(list_1, list_2))
```