# Is there a more compact way to convert a sequence of (key,value) tuples into a {key:[value,..],..} dict?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key-value

I have a sequence of tuples `itemList` in the format `(key, value)` and I want to convert the items in that list into a `dict` in the format `{key : [value, ..], ..}`. A specific `key` value may appear in `itemList` multiple times with a matching or new `value`, and I want to record these values as well (which is why simply using `dict(itemList)` does not work).

I'm using `Python2.7.9` and looking for ways to miniaturize this code:

```
newDict = dict()
for k,v in itemList:  # itemList contains the tuples described above.
    if k in newDict:
        newDict[k].append(v)
    else:
        newDict[k] = [v]
```

I've tried using `map()` and `list-comprehensions` in combination with `newDict.update(..)` but none have worked out as intended.

I've looked at [this similar question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586310/python-convert-list-of-key-value-tuples-into-dictionary) but the format of my inputs and desired output are considerably different.

(For those wondering, *"Why would you want to change this perfectly acceptable code?"*: I'm interested in finding alternative ways of applying Python's built-ins and modules more as an academic exercise, rather than to purposefully avoid something functional and comprehensible.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to shorten your code, like this

```
newDict = {}
for k, v in itemList:
    newDict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

The `setdefault` will look for the key in the dictionary, if it is not found it will assign the second parameter to it and return it.

If the key is found in the dictionary, it will simply return the corresponding value.

---

Alternatively, you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), like this

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in itemList:
    result[k].append(v)
```

This is similar to the `setdefault` approach. If the key is not found in the dictionary, then the function passed to `defaultdict` constructor will be called to create a new value.

Comment: These are really interesting methods! I've used `dict.get(SomeThing, dict())` that way before, but I hadn't noticed `setdefault`! +1
I should also probably take a look at `collections`, since I see it around a lot but have been putting it off for a while...

Answer (score 0):

This single line can replace the code posted, but is considerably harder to read. It's probably not very fast, either, since it has to iterate through `itemList` several times.

`newDict = dict((k, [_v for _k,_v in itemList if _k == k]) for k in set(i[0] for i in itemList))`

Comment: This has quadratic runtime complexity. It would become very inefficient if the `itemList` is big.

Comment: @thefourtheye I figured it would be pretty taxing to run a list comprehension inside of another iterator, yeah... It was just a solution I found. Admittedly, it is not a good replacement. XD

Comment: @thefourtheye This revised version only iterates through unique `itemList` keys (after finding them), rather than for every single `itemList` item. It's not great, but it's a lot better.