# Convert String to json python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this type of string given by my lambda function

> aws-internal/3 aws-sdk-java/1.11.432
>   Linux/4.9.124-0.1.ac.198.71.329.metal1.x86_64
>   OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.181-b13 java/1.8.0_181

Now i want to convert this string into Json like

```
{
aws-internal:3,
aws-sdk-java:1.11.432,
 Linux:/4.9.124-0.1.ac.198.71.329.metal1.x86_64 
}
```

Please Give me a suggestion i search many website and library

Comment: `str.split()` at spaces, for each `str.split('/')` at `/` :  use the resulting  list of 2-piece-lists to construct a `dict`. throw away the tuple `("java","1.8.0_181")` or delete the key `"java"` afterwards. stuff the dict into `json.dump()`. See [how-to-convert-list-of-key-value-tuples-into-dictionar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586310/how-to-convert-list-of-key-value-tuples-into-dictionary) for how list of tuples to dict works.

Comment: Thansk @PatrickArtner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with something like:

```
items = dict(a.split('/') for a in a_string.split())
```

#### Test Code:

```
a_string='aws-internal/3 aws-sdk-java/1.11.432 Linux/4.9.124-0.1.ac.198.71.329.metal1.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.181-b13 java/1.8.0_181'
items = dict(a.split('/') for a in a_string.split())
print(items)
```

#### Results

```
{
    'aws-internal': '3', 
    'aws-sdk-java': '1.11.432', 
    'Linux': '4.9.124-0.1.ac.198.71.329.metal1.x86_64', 
    'OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM': '25.181-b13', 
    'java': '1.8.0_181'
}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to use `a.rpartition('/')[::2]` instead of split to ensure you get a 2-tuple to feed to `dict()`. That'd allow for keys with no values or keys containing a `/` itself... whether that's desirable or not is probably up to the OP to decide though.