# Convert list of 2D lists to Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to convert a list of lists to a dictionary.
Each list must have 2 elements and if it does not, it should append 2nd element 'None'.  That is where I'm (*was*) stuck.

Initial list of the form:

```
test = [['A', 27], ['B', 33], ['C', 42], ['D']]
```

Final dictionary should be of the form:

```
dictionary = {'A': 27, 'B':33, 'C': 42, 'D': 'None'}
```

I'm new to coding and for loops are a weak point for me.
I've started with:

```
for n in range(0, len(test1)):
    d = dict(test1[n])
```

But I am well and truly lost.

My thought process is: get all elements of the list (each sub-list) and append 'None' to any 1D elements... I'm just not sure how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert list of key-value tuples into dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586310/how-to-convert-list-of-key-value-tuples-into-dictionary)

Comment: Could you please add a plain python tag to your question?

Comment: `None` or `'None'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... I think my question was a little poorly worded.  The crux of the issue was iterating over the list to insure all sub-lists contain 2 elements.

```
# Declare test list
test = [['A', 27], ['B', 33], ['C', 42], ['D']]

# Create max len variable
max_len = max(len(item) for item in test)

# Verify all lists within test contain 2 elements
# If not, append 'none'
for item in test:
  while len(item) < max_len:
    item.append(None)
test

# Create dictionary from list
contacts_dict = dict(test)
contacts_dict
```

Comment: This will not produce the result you are currently requesting in your question. Please fix the question. There are edit button beneath all your posts. Please use them. Also, if you could fix your tags as requested while you're at it, that would be very nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter as you go:

```
d = {x[0]: x[1] if len(x) == 2 else None for x in test}
```

Or you can use the `dict` constructor:

```
d = dict(x if len(x) == 2 else (x[0], None) for x in test)
```