# How to store the 2 outputs one as the key and the other as value in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, machine-learning

How to store the 2 output one as the key and the other as the value in a dictionary whether the key and value have the corresponding index in the output respectively in python

What i have done:

```
olabel = []
ldate = []
label = olabel.append(output)
date = ldate.append(ld) 
outputList = {label[i]:date[i]  for i in range(10)}
```

The 2 output from my K Nearest neigbour will be the output and ld.So for example the first 2 output from my K Nearest Neighbor is:

```
output = 'Light1on'
ld = '2019-10-28 09:59:00'
```

The output should be the outputList where the label  and date will be updated to respective list which will be make into dictionary with their coresspondinding index form their list into the dictionary:

```
label=['Light1on']
date =['2019-10-28 09:59:00']
outputList = [Light1on:2019-10-28 09:59:00]
```

Updated once:

```
label=['Light1on','Light2on']
date =['2019-10-28 09:59:00','2019-10-28 10:59:00']
outputList = [Light1on:2019-10-28 09:59:00, Light2on:2019-10-28 10:59:00]
```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586310/how-to-convert-list-of-key-value-tuples-into-dictionary

Comment: @ZH Law check the answer I posted does it solve your problem?

Comment: @ZH Law please accept the answer if it helped you. You can do it by clicking the tick mark next to the answer. It helps the community at large in identifying the correct answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip()` can be used to achieve what you wanted.

```
label=["something","anything","nothing"]
date=['31st feb','32nd dec','1st jan']
outputList={i:j for i,j in zip(label,date)}
print(outputList)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'something': '31st feb', 'anything': '32nd dec', 'nothing': '1st jan'}
```

**Errors in your code**

```
label = olabel.append(output)
date = ldate.append(ld)
```

No matter how many elements you append `label` is `None` because `append()` does not return anything it modifies the list in-place.

If you want to copy `olabel`'s values to `label` then you do this.

```
olabel.append(output)
label=olabel[:]
```