# Fast conversion of a list with key-value with duplicate keys into a dictionary

Tags: python

In my Python script, I have a list `l` filled with pairs of numbers. I need to convert them to a dict object, with as keys each unique number in the list, and as values a list of numbers the key was paired with, so:

input:

```
l = [(1,2),
     (1,3),
     (2,3),
     (2,4),
     (5,4),
     (5,1)]
```

Output:

```
d = {1:[2,3,5],
     2:[1,3,4],
     3:[1,2],
     4:[2,5],
     5:[4,1]}
```

Solving this is not a new question, see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777132/11427660):

```
d = dict()
[d [t [0]].append(t [1]) if t [0] in list(d.keys()) 
          else d.update({t [0]: [t [1]]}) for t in l]
```

Unfortunately this solution is simply not fast enough if `l` becomes long (in the order of 10^6 pairs). Can anyone think of a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict(list)` here to do a reverse grouping of keys and values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [(1,2),
     (1,3),
     (2,3),
     (2,4),
     (5,4),
     (5,1)]

d = defaultdict(list)
for x, y in l:
    d[x].append(y)
    d[y].append(x)

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [2, 3, 5], 2: [1, 3, 4], 3: [1, 2], 4: [2, 5], 5: [4, 1]})
```

As [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60970740/fast-conversion-of-a-list-with-key-value-with-duplicate-keys-into-a-dictionary/60970786#comment107868515_60970786) pointed out in the comments, you can use `defaultdict(set)` to handle reverse tuples like `(1, 5)` and `(5, 1)`, since duplicate pairs will be added.

```
d = defaultdict(set)
for x, y in l:
    d[x].add(y)
    d[y].add(x)

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {1: {2, 3, 5}, 2: {1, 3, 4}, 3: {1, 2}, 4: {2, 5}, 5: {1, 4}})
```

**Time Complexity**

The above solutions will operate in `O(N)` time, since they needs to scan every pair in the list of size `N`.

Comment: As a slight tweak, you might want to use `defaultdict(set)`, if pairs like `(1,5)` and `(5, 1)` can be in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Times from code below:

> Duration of defaultdict solution: 0:00:02.832145
>  Duration of
>   original solution: 0:00:02.925972
>  Duration of through:
>   0:00:02.401376

So you can see that defaultdict will help, but most of the time it takes to go through the list. If the elements are not to be repeated, you can change the type to `set`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from random import randrange
from datetime import datetime


def gen():
    for i in range(1000000):
        yield randrange(1, 5), randrange(1, 5)


t1 = datetime.now()

# defaultdict solution
groups = defaultdict(list)
for numbers in gen():
    groups[numbers[0]].append(numbers[1])
    groups[numbers[1]].append(numbers[0])

t2 = datetime.now()
print(f"Duration of defaultdict solution: {t2 - t1}")

# original solution
d = dict()
[d[t[0]].append(t[1]) if t[0] in list(d.keys()) else d.update({t[0]: [t[1]]}) for t in gen()]
t3 = datetime.now()
print(f"Duration of original solution: {t3 - t2}")

# through
for numbers in gen():
    pass

t4 = datetime.now()
print(f"Duration of through: {t4 - t3}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the speed comparisons. This is insightful :)