# Return the difference of two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

What I am trying to do is return the key, value pair difference between two dictionaries.

This simple bit of code does the trick:

```
remaining_macs = xlsx_macs.items() - xmc_macs.items()
```

But is returning a set as below, instead of the key, value dictionary pairs I would like?

```
{('70:B5:E8:C5:06:6B', 'Staff-Group'), ('34:9F:7B:56:53:C0', 'Printer-Group'), ('74:BF:C0:DE:7E:74', 'Printer-Group'), ('D4:3D:7E:BB:49:C4', 'Staff-Group'), ('8C:8C:AA:B5:1D:D4', 'Staff-Group')}
```

This is the original format of the dictionaries:

xlsx_macs:

```
{'8C:8C:AA:B5:1D:D4': 'Staff-Group', '70:B5:E8:C5:06:6B': 'Staff-Group', 'D4:3D:7E:BB:49:C4': 'Staff-Group', '34:9F:7B:56:06:23': 'Printer-Group', '34:9F:7B:56:53:C0': 'Printer-Group', '74:BF:C0:DE:7E:74': 'Printer-Group', 'BC:F3:10:E2:BF:40': 'Access Points', 'BC:F3:10:E2:C6:C0': 'Access Points', 'BC:F3:10:E2:CB:00': 'Access Points', '00:13:5E:8D:19:EE': 'VoIP Phones', '44:47:CC:DF:75:AB': 'CCTV-Group', '00:08:5D:75:D1:BB': 'Voice-Group', '00:08:5D:75:D1:A5': 'Voice-Group', '00:08:5D:57:17:30': 'Voice-Group', ...}
```

xmc_macs:

```
{'00:0A:83:02:35:8E': 'Salto-Group', '00:0A:83:02:3D:7D': 'Salto-Group', '00:0A:83:02:3D:AE': 'Salto-Group', '00:0A:83:02:40:C8': 'Salto-Group', '00:0A:83:02:40:C9': 'Salto-Group', '00:0A:83:02:40:D0': 'Salto-Group', '00:0A:83:02:40:DF': 'Salto-Group', '34:9F:7B:56:06:23': 'Printer-Group', 'BC:F3:10:E2:BF:40': 'Access Points', 'BC:F3:10:E2:C6:C0': 'Access Points', 'BC:F3:10:E2:CB:00': 'Access Points', 'BC:F3:10:E2:D1:00': 'Access Points', 'BC:F3:10:E2:D4:00': 'Access Points', 'BC:F3:10:E3:BD:40': 'Access Points', ...}
```

So I am struggling with the output that I want to remain as a dictionary, or finding some code that does the job better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert list of key-value tuples into dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586310/how-to-convert-list-of-key-value-tuples-into-dictionary) This is for a list, but `dict()` takes _any iterable_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your result to a dictionary:

```
remaining_macs = dict(xlsx_macs.items() - xmc_macs.items())
```

Example:

```
>>> dict({('70:B5:E8:C5:06:6B', 'Staff-Group'), ('34:9F:7B:56:53:C0', 'Printer-Group'), ('74:BF:C0:DE:7E:74', 'Printer-Group'), ('D4:3D:7E:BB:49:C4', 'Staff-Group'), ('8C:8C:AA:B5:1D:D4', 'Staff-Group')})
{'74:BF:C0:DE:7E:74': 'Printer-Group', 'D4:3D:7E:BB:49:C4': 'Staff-Group', '70:B5:E8:C5:06:6B': 'Staff-Group', '8C:8C:AA:B5:1D:D4': 'Staff-Group', '34:9F:7B:56:53:C0': 'Printer-Group'}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586310/how-to-convert-list-of-key-value-tuples-into-dictionary