# change list to map in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list with the following value

```
[(b'abc', '123'), (b'xyz', '456'), (b'cde', '785')]
```

I need to change it to map with key value pair :

```
('abc','123'),('xyz','456'),('cde','785')
```

Is there a method that I can use.

Comment: `{k.decode(): v for k, v in data}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Comment: And [How to convert list of key-value tuples into dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6586310/4046632)

Comment: @flakes is the code changing it to a dictionary. Thank you

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem for you - converting the byte-string to string or converting the list of key, value tuples into list, but BOTH are long answered on SO and your question is clear duplicate. You just did no research at all

Comment: Of course, I  mean converting the list of key, value tuples into dict. Sorry for the mistake in the comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_list = [(b'abc', '123'), (b'xyz', '456'), (b'cde', '785')]
dic={}
for key,value in my_list:
    dic[key.decode()]=value
print(dic) #{'abc': '123', 'xyz': '456', 'cde': '785'}
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, dictionaries are the simplest implementation of a map.

```
L=[(b'abc', '123'), (b'xyz', '456'), (b'cde', '785')]

d={}
for i in L:
    d[i[0]]=i[1]

print(d)
```

This code will turn your list into a dictionary

Hope it helps✌️

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise the *dict()* function in conjunction with a generator as follows:

```
L = [(b'abc', '123'), (b'xyz', '456'), (b'cde', '785')]

D = dict((x.decode(), y) for x, y in L)

print(D)
```

**Output:**

```
{'abc': '123', 'xyz': '456', 'cde': '785'}
```